# android listview setadapter crash

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, arraylist

I'm new on android, I'm tryng to display an array on a listview
this is the xml where I set the listview:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

an here is MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listView ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Elemento 1", 
                                         "Elemento 2",
                                         "Elemento 3",
                                         "Elemento 4", 
                                         "Elemento 5", 
                                         "Elemento 6", 
                                         "Elemento 7", 
                                         "Elemento 8" 
                                        };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.id.text1, values);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter); 

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

so, the problem is, everything goes great, until I write:

```
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I run the app, and it just crashes, App has stopped. when I comment this section of code, it runs but obviously doesn't show anything. I run it on my tablet, it's on ICS

thanks in advance.

Comment: You have two listview variables in your code, are you sure you're using the correct one?

Comment: I am guessing listview belongs to `fragment_main.xml` and you are getting `NullPointerException`

Comment: If you are, then it might be that your layout doesn't have the listview with the provided Id

Comment: where is yur listview in activity xml or in fragment main?

Comment: where this id is belongs R.id.lv in activity_main or fragment_main ?

Comment: @DevCarlsberg it's on fragment_main.xml

Comment: then put your listview in activty xml. and let me know its working or not?

Comment: yeah that was the problem, thank you very much guys.

Comment: I'm sorry guys and thanks to Dev Carlsberg. I'd fix it yet, I did not realize I'd put the listview on my fragment_main.xml file. and I had 

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

that means the correct layout where the listview should be is activity_main.xml
so I'd just delete the

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

from the fragment_main.xml file and put it in the activity_main.xml and worked perfectly.
thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry guys and thanks to Dev Carlsberg. I'd fix it yet, I did not realize I'd put the listview on my fragment_main.xml file. and I had:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

that means the correct layout where the listview should be is `activity_main.xml` so I'd just delete the:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/lv" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

from the `fragment_main.xml` file and put it in the `activity_main.xml` and worked perfectly. 
thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
      android.R.id.text1, values);
```

with

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Comment: well, I had it this way before, didn't work, I found someone said it would be better this way, so I'd change it, still doesn't work

Comment: unfortunately application has stopped, It's due to a nullpointerexception. but I'd fix it yet.

Comment: I'm sorry guys and thanks to Dev Carlsberg. I'd fix it yet, I did not realize I'd put the listview on my fragment_main.xml file. and I had 

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

that means the correct layout where the listview should be is activity_main.xml
so I'd just delete the

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

from the fragment_main.xml file and put it in the activity_main.xml and worked perfectly.
thanks again